# Why in Android studio update patch is not updating?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing a weird behavior of Android studio updation.I have 2 machines using Windows operating system.Last week, I updated android studio on one of my machines it updated normally nothing is weird but now I am updating android studio on my second machine it is not updating.Here is the picture to provide proper information
[image: To update android studio this dialogue comes up]

On the dialogue i selected update and restart option then it started downloading
as in the picture shown
[image]

after downloading it restarted but it was not updated.i don't why did happened?Am i missing anything?

Note: Currently my android studio version is 1.1 and updating to 1.4